# Using PostGIS on Python 3

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

I'm using Python 3 and need to connect to postGre with postGIS extensions.
I'm intending to use a psycopg2 driver.
This [PPyGIS](http://www.fabianowski.eu/projects/ppygis/index.html) is the only extension I found, but it works on python 2.7 not 3.3.0.
Any one knows a solution working on 3.3.0 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are not doing anything fancy with the geometry objects on the client side (Python), psycopg2 can get most basic info using native data types with [geometry accessors](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors), or other GIS [output formats](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs) like [GeoJSON](http://www.geojson.org/). Let the server (PostgreSQL/PostGIS) do the hard work.

Here is a random example to return the GeoJSON to shapes that are within 1 km of a point of interest:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='postgis', user='postgres')
curs = conn.cursor()

# Find the distance within 1 km of point-of-interest
poi = (-124.3, 53.2)  # longitude, latitude

# Table 'my_points' has a geography column 'geog'
curs.execute("""\
SELECT gid, ST_AsGeoJSON(geog), ST_Distance(geog, poi)
FROM my_points, (SELECT ST_MakePoint(%s, %s)::geography AS poi) AS f
WHERE ST_DWithin(geog, poi, 1000);""", poi)

for row in curs.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Comment: It will basic, having a layer of points on a map. As an option measure distance between two points.

Comment: @MilleBii if all you need is the distance, then psycopg2 is all you need. PPyGIS is only useful if you need to do some custom things on the actual geometry/geography on the client side with Python, rather than on the server side with PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Comment: You may also define specific adapters to let _psycopg2_ format the geo-queries. Using for example geometries from *pygeoif*:

def adapt_point(pt):
    return AsIs("ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({}, {}), 4326)".format(adapt(pt.x), adapt(pt.y)));

register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)

Answer (score 3):

You may actually use [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/) or [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org), but both libraries have a long list of dependencies.

If you have only very few usecases, you might also implement a small protocol yourself, based on the super slick [pygeoif](https://github.com/cleder/pygeoif) library, like the example below

```
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs, adapt
from pygeoif.geometry import Point

def adapt_point(pt):
    return AsIs("ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({}, {}), 4326)".format(adapt(pt.x), adapt(pt.y)))

register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was asked the Geopandas package added

```
classmethod GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom', 
    crs=None, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, parse_dates=None, params=None)
```

which will retrieve a geodataframe from a sql table with a geometry column

http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to give the geometry as wkb. With it you can unse all functunalites of psycopg2 like execute_values

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
from osgeo import ogr

d = [{'id' : 1, 'name' : 'A', 'the_geom': ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POINT({} {})'.format(5.085679, 45.042005)).ExportToWkb()},
{'id' : 2, 'name' : 'B','the_geom': ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt('POINT({} {})'.format(-1.182751, 46.170237)).ExportToWkb() }]

sql = 'INSERT INTO mon_schema.ma_table (id, name the_geom) VALUES %s'
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(pgCur, sql, d)
```